# mongodb how to filter by distance

Tags: mongodb, gis

Let's say I have a users collection like this:

```
{
  "lastName": "Doe",
  "firstName": "John",
   ...
  "location": {
    "country": "USA",
    "city": "New York",
     ...
    "lat": 123456,
    "lon": 123456
  }
}
```

I want to filter my collection by distance: `Return all users near 100 km`.
There is in the document [$near](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/near/). But can't find how to use it.

I have an example like this :

```
db.users.find({
    location: {
        $near: [-73.9667, 40.78],
        $maxDistance: 100000
    }
});
```

So I think my issue is how to tell mongo he has to check `user.location.lat` and `user.location.lon` to calculate distance.

Answer (score 1):

With your dataset, you can't.

The problem is that you don't have a geo index.  You need one to do geo searches.

To be able to achieve what you want, you need to restructure your dataset like so:

```
{
  "lastName": "Doe",
  "firstName": "John",
   ...
  "location": {
    "country": "USA",
    "city": "New York",
     ...
    "coords": [123456, 123456]
  }
}
```

The `coords` array is `[latitude, longitude]`.  Then you need to create a 2d index on that field.

Comment: Is there another way to do the index without updating my model ?